# Nginx не загружает файл через django admin

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, есть связка с Django + Nginx + PostgreSQL
В Django есть строка

```
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Изображение')
```

позволяющая загружать изображения  и размещать их в корне

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Если запускать приложение Django путём `python3 manage.py runserver`,
а режим `DEBUG = False` и не помещать в контейнер Docker, то приложение отработает и загрузит в /media/<year>/<m>/<d>/image.jpg - файл.

Проблемы начинаются после размещения приложения в docker и запуска его в контейнере, nginx, попытка загрузки через поле, в логах показывает успешную загрузку

```
POST /admin/app/prod/2/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://192.168.xx.xx/admin/app/prod/2/change/
```

и как прежде папки с датами не создаются.
Но стоит вручную добавить этот файл создав папки  `/media/\<year>/\<m>/\<d>\/image.jpg`
nginx успешно отрабатывает и показывает загруженный файл на странице.
Конфигурация nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        client_body_buffer_size    10m;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /media/;
    }

}
```

А docker-compose выглядит так

```
version: "3"

services:

  
    
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - ./static_dev/:/static_dev
      - ./media/:/media
      - ./static/:/static
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    
nginx:
        build:
          context: ./docker/nginx
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
          - postgresdb
          - web
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - ./static_dev/:/static_dev
          - ./media/:/media
          - ./static/:/static
          - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
  
WORKDIR /usr/scr/app

COPY requirements.txt .

COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod -x /usr/scr/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY . .
```

settings.py

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = False
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'mainapp.auth.EmailAuthBackend',
]
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'mainapp.apps.MainappConfig',
    'specs',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',
    'psycopg2',
    'captcha',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'shop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'shop.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.getenv('ENGINE_DB'),
        "NAME": os.getenv('NAME_DB'),
        "USER": os.getenv('USER_DB'),
        "PASSWORD": os.getenv('PASSWORD_DB'),
        "HOST": os.getenv('HOST_DB'),
        "PORT": os.getenv('PORT_DB'),
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_dev'),
)

CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"
INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]
```

Dockerfile nginx

```
FROM nginx
  
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**Всё сработало!** Спасибо за подсказку **andreymal**
В настройках *settings.py* сменил:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/usr/scr/app/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Это путь в самом контейнере docker.

Comment: Покажите настройки django и докерфайл

Comment: Обновил информацию.

Comment: Ну, видимо, путь `MEDIA_ROOT` прописан не тот, который вам нужен

Comment: В самом docker есть 

/usr/scr/app/media
и
/media
получается прописать нужно полный путь первого варианта?

Comment: Если вы хотите именно такой путь, значит его нужно прописать и в volumes тоже

Comment: Вопрос не в том какой я хочу путь :) Вопрос в том что бы оно работало и оно заработало! Спасибо Вам за подсказку!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Огромное спасибо!
Сайчас отредактирую и напишу решение!